# WPF binding backcode objects to UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

Can anyone explain to me how to bind a collection, for example a `String[]` object to a WPF `ListBox` (in xaml) and how it works because I am sick after reading tutorials on MSDN and other sites.  I still have no idea how to do it.

Let's assume that I have in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
String[] bigBadWolf = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
```

I want `bigBadWolf` to be bound with `ListBox` in xaml (I want each member of `bigBadWolf` to be displayed in `ListBox` vertically (something like playlist)).

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, then I would recommend that you define a `DependencyProperty` to bind to instead:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BigBadWolfProperty = DependencyProperty.
    Register("BigBadWolf", typeof(string[]), typeof(MainWindow), new
    UIPropertyMetadata(100.0));

public string[] BigBadWolf
{
    get { return (string[])GetValue(BigBadWolfProperty); }
    set { SetValue(BigBadWolfProperty, value); }
}
```

Then, you must set your `DataContext`... the easiest (but not best) way is to do this in the constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Now bind to the property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BigBadWolf}" />
```

Please note that it is more usual in WPF to use an `ObservableCollection<T>` collection instead.

Comment: Still dont get it ;/ Binding Collection object like list to ItemSource Property of ListBox impossible in WPF. This whole mess must be done?

Comment: WPF is a very different language from WinForms or ASP.NET. If you want to use it to develop, then you have a *lot* of stuff to learn.